# Powershell - the if statement in a function only uses the first if even though the criteria is not met

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement, credentials

I have the following function but no matter what $Server I specify, the first if statement is always used even though the criteria is not met. This causes the wrong credentials to be used. I've tried numerous re-writes "" in different places, with and without wildcards but I always have the same issue. Its probably a simple oversight but I cant spot it (powershell newbie).

```
$CredsFile = "C:\cred.txt"

Function DriveSpace {

$Server= "Myserver"

if ($Server -contains "application" -or "web") {
    $password = get-content $CredsFile | convertto-securestring
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $Server"\username",$password
    $Output = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $Server -Credential $cred| 
        Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | 
        Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}} |Out-String
}
Else {      
    $Output = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $Server| 
    Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | 
    Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}} |Out-String
} 
$Output

}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: In addition to the correct answers you have, `-contains` is probably not the comparison operator you're looking for - this is used to check the presence of an element in an array. You most likely want `-match` instead.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, a simple fix but an easy cock up for a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Compound If statements treat each clause as a discrete test.

```
if ($Server -contains "application" -or "web")
```

Is going to evaluate `$Server -contains "application"` and `"web"` separately, and then cast the result of each one as [bool].  "Web" is a non-null string, which is always going to return $true when cast as [bool].

You need to make the second clause a complete test expression that will stand on it's own:

```
if ($Server -contains "application" -or $Server -contains "web")
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not working the way you think it is.

```
$Server -contains "application" -or "web"
```

Using brackets to show how it is being interpreted. This statement is the same as yours.

```
($Server -contains "application") -or ("web")
```

It should instead be

```
$Server -contains "application" -or $Server -contains "web"
```

What is happening is the this is being seen as two statements.

```
$Server -contains "application"
```

and

```
"web"
```

A non null non empty string will resolve as True. That is why your original statement was firing since `"Web"` is a true condition on its own. If it helps consider the following statement that would return `"True"`.

```
If("web"){"True"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `"web"` always is true.  Change your statement to `if ($Server -contains "application" -or $Server -contains "web")`